# Swift 4: Mask not working for UIImage?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, animation, mask

I'm running the code below (simplified to important blocks) trying to make a side menu animation like the one done in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ej5laXv2dzQ&vl=en. I'm trying to do the entire project without using Storyboard (heard it's a good practice, I'm sorta a newbie to iOS development lol), which means I need to create the mask for the side menu programmatically, and have changed some code to fit my needs. Whenever I run the code below, however, the image view that I'm setting the mask on disappears. The program builds, but the side menu image view just isn't appearing (image shown below). Where am I going wrong? Thanks.

```
let maskView: UIImageView = {
    let iv = UIImageView()
    iv.backgroundColor = .blue
    return iv
}()

let sideMenu: UIImageView = {
    let iv = UIImageView()
    iv.image = "example.png"
    iv.frame.origin.x = -80 //Setting side menu image view to off the left side of the screen so that it can slide in when tapped
    return iv
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.addSubview(maskView)
    view.addSubview(sideMenu)

    maskView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    maskView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    maskView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: 60).isActive = true
    maskView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.frame.height).isActive = true

    sideMenu.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    sideMenu.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true // So when tapped, it slides 80px to the right, entering the screen
    sideMenu.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: 80).isActive = true
    sideMenu.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.frame.height).isActive = true

    sideMenu.mask = maskView // this is always the line that makes the sideMenu disappear
}
```

Image of the issue (should have a white background for the side menu on the left):

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7RhDl.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set Y constraint like top or centerY

```
maskView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
sideMenu.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
```

Comment: Sorry, that didn't work. Same issue :( Thanks though

Comment: Is that different from building? Because it builds fine, just doesn't display the sideMenu

Comment: you add both views to the self.view then no need for the mask

Comment: One is the mask for the other

Comment: remove the mask it's already added when you add the views as subviews , add the y constraint , also setting x frame has no value when using constraints , set your constraint properly and slide by changing the constant value of the leftAnchor constraint